# Dispatch an action based on the page the user is at

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
const handleChangeCurrency = currency => {
/*if(user on currencyList component page) dispatch below twos*/
        dispatch({
            type: 'currencyList/emptyCurrencyList',
            payload: []
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'currencyList/setCurrencyListConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
/*if(user on currency component page) dispatch below twos*/
        dispatch({
            type: 'globalStats/setGlobalStatsConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'currency/setCurrencyConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
    }
```

Here, I have two components `CurrencyList` and `Currency`(specific) both of which render on different `route`s. But, I have a `CurrencyChanger` component which is universal i.e., is present on the whole application irrespective of `route`.
Now, I want to dispatch some `actions` depending upon the page user is at. I don't wanna dispatch all the four actions everytime as it makes the application slow.
Is there anything I can put inside `if else` block to dispatch them conditionally.

Comment: Have you tried using ``useLocation()`` ?

Comment: Another option, if you're using  `connected-react-router`, is to simply read the current route from the redux state before dispatching.

Comment: May you pass props from parent component?

Comment: @Monstar Yes, I searched and found about ```useLocation``` and it worked. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @misha-from-lviv Yes, I could've done that but I'm using redux store so I'm avoiding sending states and props. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You should answer your question then and mark it as resolved, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, one simple way is to use [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation):

```js
const location = useLocation();

const handleChangeCurrency = currency => {
    if(location.pathname === "/currency"){
        dispatch({
            type: 'currencyList/emptyCurrencyList',
            payload: []
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'currencyList/setCurrencyListConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
    } else if(location.pathname === "/currencyList"){
        dispatch({
            type: 'globalStats/setGlobalStatsConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'currency/setCurrencyConvertedState',
            payload: true
        })
    }
}
```